# Why is image dimension in property different from Photoshop raw photo editor?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

To put it simply, say I have an image in `cr2` format, and in property, it says the dimension is `6020 x 4015`:

[image: Image property]

But the same image when opened in Photoshop raw photo editor, shows a different dimension, namely `6000 x 4000`:

[image: raw photo editor view]

Which one is the real dimension of the image? And what caused this difference?

Comment: the answer to above proposed question contains general points which pertain to any raw file as well as camera specific ones.

Comment: Also related: [Why are effective pixels greater than the actual resolution?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9738/15871) and [Why do some cameras have a higher resolution sensor even though the max resolution is smaller?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/65062/15871)